# Planning a roadbed in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, road, curvature, planning

I am just starting to look into the QGIS project.

I wish to plan a roadbed on my property. I would like to start with a map with topographic information (height, direction, distance) and draw the roadbed on the map.

I would then like to be able to read the gradient and distance of the planned roadbed as well as curvature and curve radii. Maybe also calculate the amount of mass to be removed or filled to support a roadbed.

Would QGIS be a suitable tool to do this?

If so, I would like to get involved in the project and learn to use the program.

At this stage I am not even sure where I could find a response to my question, if any.

Comment: If there are any sort of drainage concerns with the road, I highly recommend hiring an engineer to make sure you are not going to cause yourself problems in the future. Dealing with water runoff is a big reason to use an engineer to correctly design any ditches and piping. The cost of an engineer pays for itself really quickly when your road blows out and you have to hire a contractor to repair it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. There are places on the property where drainage will have to be dealt with. We live in a rainy place. But my project is still very far from being realized in the field. It is only on paper so far, and maybe soon on the computer screen. I hope to learn more about the challenges the project may bring through making a GIS map with much information in it. Even if it never gets to realization I hope it can be a good learning experience.

Answer (score 2):

Of course suitable.

Do you have any data already to start with your project?

I think at least you will need a relatively high resolution digital elevation model from which various geomorphological parameters may derive. Add this to your project as a raster source and calculate the other parameters with the terrain analysis tool you prefer (processing > toolbox).

Then create a new layer (shapefile should do the trick) for your roadbed(s) and start editing it.

Last step would be to clip the above created rasters to the roadbeds and carry out the statistics you need.

This in detail covers a certain pile of knowledge, so consider to ask details in extra posts, and consider this as a starting point for your further research.

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift reply. The most important data will be a good map with the necessary data. The local municipality has an online map that I have been using so far, but I do not know if I can download this and if it then would have the features I need. If I would contact the municipality, are there certain things I should ask for in a map? If I get a good map I can start drawing on it myself.

Comment: I talked to the municipality. They sell what they call a "technical map". It has vector data. The man suggested that an autocad file would be usable for me. It will have .dwg or .dxf extensions.

Comment: One of the core concepts of gis mapping is that map data is made up of separate layers. If you're not already familiar with this concept, I recommend familiarizing yourself with it before proceeding. Many layers are available for free once you know what to look for, so you may not need to pay for the technical map from the municipality. A quick google search leads to many sources to explain this concept, here is just one example: http://www.gagecs.com/images/gallery/single/data/images26/gisdata.jpg

Comment: Thank you for your advice. As I said in my original question I am just starting to look into this project. There are no doubt many concepts I need to learn more about, including layers. But I do remember layers from when GIS was part of my studies some 20 years ago. I will check what is available of free or purchased layers. Thank you for the link.

Comment: The most important layer for my project now will be topography (altitude differences).

Comment: I have gotten two files with .dwg extensions for the municipality. How do I get these into the qgis program so I can start working with them?

Comment: You cannot open dwg directly (at this state of development), you need to convert them to dxf. I usually use a tool called 'Teigha file converter' for this https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/TeighaFileConverter dxf files can be opened in qgis with the normal add vector layer funcionality. these use to have an attribute called 'Layer' on wich i recommend to make a categorized renderer. This makes it easier  for you to choose what information you might need from the dxf file.

Comment: I don't find out how to post comments or answers.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you for your help. Now I have gotten my map on the qgis screen. I converted them in "Teigha" from .dwg to .dxf files, if I get all the letters here correctly. My map consists now of two files, one with the topographic information and buildings, and an other file with property boundaries. The boundaries (file 2)seem to be on the right place in the map (file 1), that happened automatically without my interference. So I wish to start drawing a roadbed on the map. I tried the menu like this:  Layer > Create layer > New Spatialite Layer (my best guess), but I did not succeed.

Comment: The "OK" button was grey and not possible to click. 
I did not enter a database (because I don't have one), maybe that was why I did not succeed with this try? I hope someone can answer my question or point me to a beginners tutorial on youtube or something similar.

Comment: Maybe I did find out how to add comments after all. I got an error message for a long time.